# How to validate row on delete?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive, which validates row and show error is some row has duplicate value, here is the code:

```
  app.directive('isUniqueRow', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                isUniqueRow: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
                var rows = scope.isUniqueRow;
                scope.$watch('ngModel', function(v) {
                    if(!v || v == '') {
                      c.$setValidity('unique', true);
                      return;
                    }


                    var count = 0;
                    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
                        if(rows[i].key == v) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    c.$setValidity('unique', count < 2);
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

It's working fine except one issue, see the plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/IRkgMPRw3Chd7x43Fzdv?p=preview

Issue:

1. Type **text1** in the first row
2. Add another row
3. Type **text1** again in the second row, it will show error
4. Delete first row, the error is still on form.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your `$watch` code with following:

```
scope.$watch('isUniqueRow', function() {             // <== Modified line
  var v = scope.ngModel;                             // <== New line
  if(!v || v == '') {
    c.$setValidity('unique', true);
    return;
  }


  var count = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    if(rows[i].key == v) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  c.$setValidity('unique', count < 2);
}, true);                                           // <== Modified line
```

We are basically **deeply watching** (by passing `true` at the last) over the list also. So whenever we are removing/adding/updating any item from that list (`rows`) we again validating the values.

**See the working example below**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.objs = [{}];

  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.objs.push({});
  }

  $scope.delete = function(index) {
    $scope.objs.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

app.directive('isUniqueRow', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      isUniqueRow: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
      var rows = scope.isUniqueRow;

      scope.$watch('isUniqueRow', function() {
        var v = scope.ngModel;
        if (!v || v == '') {
          c.$setValidity('unique', true);
          return;
        }


        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          if (rows[i].key == v) {
            count++;
          }
        }
        c.$setValidity('unique', count < 2);
      }, true);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.0"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in objs">
    <ng-form name="iForm">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="key" ng-model="row.key" is-unique-row="objs" type="text" />
            <div ng-show="iForm.key.$error.unique" style="color: #ff0000;">Must be unique</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button ng-click="delete($index)">Del</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ng-form>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its buggy; 1) Type test ...  2) Add row ... 3) Type test in second row 4) Add row 5) edit first row to test1 6) Error still showing on row 2

Comment: You didn't asked me to deep test your code :-) You have to do it. I only answered to your basic question. Well, I've updated my answer. Please check it out.